# Combining DateTime Date and String Time into a single DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

I am using asp.net MVC and I have two separate fields in my form.

One that accepts a Date and the other accepts a Time. In my ViewModel I have the following two properties:

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public string Time { get; set; } //could potentially make this of type DateTime
```

I would like to create a ReadOnly property called DateTime that returns the combined Date and Time as a DateTime.

This would be extremely simple if I could just make the Time property of type TimeSpan but unfortunately MVC does not bind the time as a timespan when using the TimePicker that I am using. It only accepts a string or a datetime.

Any ideas how I can do this?

**A couple of things I have tried that are not working:**

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public string Time { get; set; }
public DateTime DateTime => Date.Date.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(Time)); // Time = "2:00 AM"
```

**The only thing that works, but I am unsure about it is the following:**

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public DateTime Time { get; set; }
public DateTime DateTime => Date.Add(Time.TimeOfDay);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse the time into a `TimeSpan` object and add it to your current Date.

Parsing time in format `08:00 AM` could be solved with `h:mm tt` as descriped [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public string Time { get; set; }
public DateTime DateTime
{
    get
    {
         return Date.Date.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(Time, "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

In case of `Time` with type `DateTime`

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public DateTime Time { get; set; }
public DateTime DateTime
{
    get
    {
        return Date.Date.Add(Time.TimeOfDay);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BlakeRivell using the `Date` property of `DateTime` removes the time - not sure if you need it here but it's the cleaner way

Comment: what are you saying? To do Date.Date.Add instead of Date.Add?

Comment: Yes, that drops the time from your `Date` if there is one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below approach which uses TimeSpan.Parse method to reach the required output.

```
string outputTime = string.Empty; 
string timeFormat = inputTime.Substring(inputTime.Length - 2); 
switch (timeFormat)  
        {  
            case ("AM"):  
                outputTime = inputTime.Replace("AM", "");  
                break;  
            case ("PM"):  
                int hours = 0;  
                int.TryParse(inputTime.Replace("PM", ""), out hours);  
                outputTime = (hours + 12).ToString();  
                break;  
        }  
DateTime newDateTime = date.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(outputTime));
```

Comment: Doesn't work I get an error because my time is formatted like this: '08:00 AM' I don't think it likes the parse because of the AM/PM

Comment: @BlakeRivell: Please check my edited answer if it works for you.